# Как объеденить 2 сборки в одну на рантайме c#?

Tags: c#, .net, assembly

У меня есть AssemblyBuilder ab и мне нужно по строке id (из которой можно получить путь к файлу: `Path.GetFullPath(id + ".dll")`) получить сборку и "приклеить" её к ab. Делаю на .NET Framework 4.6
Кому нужны прям фулл фулл исходники: https://github.com/world-of-legends/tokensbuilder-dotnet

Comment: А зачем это делать? Может если скажешь для чего - найдется более красивое решение?

Comment: @Gordory я делаю компилятор в .net через рефлексию и мне надо добавить возможность подключения библиотек